# How to include ajax post into get form and exclude used inputs by ajax in get url? Laravel

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, laravel-5

So I have search form (I have written in laravel like HTML, but the code is self explaining; pure html answers are welcome too):

```
{!! Form::model($search, ['url' => 'projects/', 'method' => 'get']) !!}
//Select option I want to include into GET url
{!! Form::select('sort', array(0 => 'Sort: Update Date', 1 => 'Create Date', 2 => 'Follows'), null, ['id' => 'sort', 'class' => 'form-control']) !!}

//A has ajax post request to get B options. A and B shouldn't appear in GET url (exclude A and B alone - they are used to create mixed AB combinations). 
{!! Form::select('A', array(...), null, ['id' => 'A', 'class' => 'form-control']) !!}
{!! Form::select('B', array(...), null, ['id' => 'B', 'class' => 'form-control']) !!}
{!! Form::button('Add A B combination', ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}

//Include A and B combination into GET url
{!! Form::select('A_B_combinations[]', array('' => ''), null, ['id' => 'expected', 'class' => 'form-control', 'multiple', 'style' => 'display: none;']) !!}

{!! Form::submit('Search', ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

I want in get url to appear only sort option and mixed A B combinations variable.

My example ajax code:

```
$( "#A" ).change(function() {
    $.ajaxSetup({ headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('input[name="_token"]').attr('value') } });
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST", /* 'POST' works in post form, 'GET' doesn't work in get form.*/
      url: '/ajax/B',
      data: {a: a_id},
      //success: onSuccess,
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function( json ) {
          $.each(json, function(i, value) {
            $("#B").append(
                $("<option></option>")
                    .text(value.display_name)
                    .val(value.id)
            );
          });
      }
    });
});
```

Maybe I am doing everything wrong, but I have no idea how to do this one? Everything works fine if I use post method, the problem is that I want search data to appear in url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only idea I come up with is:

1. Create get form with all required inputs which should appear in url
   bar + hidden input of combined values.
2. Second post form on same page with add button and ajax options.
3. On pressing 'add' -> add combination with jquery to hidden field in
   get form.